How to avoid asyncpg params limit in query or best way to insert more then 32767 params?
Recently I started to migrate from psycopg2 library to asyncpg. I tested with different data and today I faced the problem of inserting data where there are more than 400 thousand parameters.
> E                  
> sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.asyncpg.AsyncAdapt_asyncpg_dbapi.InterfaceError:
> <class 'asyncpg.exceptions._base.InterfaceError'>: the number of query
> arguments cannot exceed 32767

I immediately googled and found this forum. It says that:

Currently postgres JDBC driver has a 32767 limit for the number of
prepared statement arguments

and

This is a PG wire protocol limitation: the number-of-parameters field
in Bind messages is int16 1. So there's little that the JDBC driver
could do differently.

I already understood that this is a limitation of postgresql itself. But how does psycopg2 cope with this? There I can easily insert even more rows into the table.
In this regard, the question is, how can I bypass this limitation or change it?
If the limitation cannot be changed, then what are the ways to insert more than 32767 parameters?
(I understand that you probably want to say that "you need to rewrite the query and insert in batches", but to be honest, I would not like to make a loop for each table where many records are inserted in one query and insert data several times. If earlier I could insert 30 thousand rows in one query, now I need to make 30 queries to insert the same data.)
p.s.
I should clarify that my query looks like this:
SQL: INSERT INTO shema.table(column1, column2, column3, column4, column5) VALUES ... ON CONFLICT (column1) DO UPDATE SET column1= excluded.column1, column2= excluded.column2, column3= excluded.column3, column4 = excluded.column4, column5= excluded.column5, but written using Sqlalchemy 2.0

It's the "values()" that contain many parameters? If so, use a temp table and insert all your data first in this table using COPY and then use INSERT INTO() SELECT to move the data from the temp table to your target. COPY is lightning fast and is not limited by just 400k values.

You are either going to need to use batching or use the process @FrankHeikens suggested. FYI, psycopg2 provides Fast execution helpers execute_batch or execute_values that do the batching for you also psycopg(3) provides Pipeline mode that speeds up batching.
